# Is it possible to interrupt the map and put another element in the middle?

Tags: next.js, mapping, jsx

I'm making a navbar in Nextjs, and I want to put a different element in the middle of the map.

```
            {navLinks.map((link, index) => (
              <li key={index}>
                <NavLink href={link.path} title={link.title} />
              </li>
            ))}
```

Is it possible to interrupt the map, let's say after 4 items put a different element, then continue the map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use if statement and if index equales 4 return your another element.

```
{navLinks.map((link, index) => {
            if (index !== 4) {
                return (
                    <li key={index}>
                        <NavLink href={link.path} title={link.title} />
                    </li>
                )
            } else {
                return (<div>your different element</div>)
            }
           
        })}
```

And if you don't want to lose your 5th index of navLinks you can include it in your return after different element;

```
{navLinks.map((link, index) => {
            if (index !== 4) {
                return (
                    <li key={index}>
                        <NavLink href={link.path} title={link.title} />
                    </li>
                )
            } else {
                return (<div>your different element
                    <li key={index}>
                        <NavLink href={link.path} title={link.title} />
                    </li>
                </div>)
            }
           
        })}
```